# Scala-Playのコンパイル時に、詳細が表示されないコンパイルエラーが出ます・・

Tags: scala, playframework

Playフレームワークを使っているのですが、コンパイル時に下記のようなエラーが出てしまいます。
書いてある通り「last compile:compile」も試しましたが、スタックトーレースに自分の書いたソースファイルは無く、原因がわかりません。
どなたか分かりますでしょうか？？

```
activator
[XXXXXX] $ compile
[info] Compiling 84 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to > /XXX/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:compile for the full output.
[error] (compile:compile) java.lang.NullPointerException
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed 2014/12/18 18:28:57
```

下記「last compile:compile」の内容です。

```
 [XXX] $ last compile:compile
 [debug] 
 [debug] Initial source changes: 
 [debug]    removed:Set()
 [debug]    added: Set(・・・)
 [debug]    modified: Set()
 [debug] Removed products: Set()
 [debug] External API changes: API Changes: Set()
 [debug] Modified binary dependencies: Set()
 [debug] Initial directly invalidated sources: Set(・・・)
 [debug] 
 [debug] Sources indirectly invalidated by:
 [debug]    product: Set()
 [debug]    binary dep: Set()
 [debug]    external source: Set()
 [debug] All initially invalidated sources: Set(・・・)
 [debug] Recompiling all 86 sources: invalidated sources (86) exceeded 50.0% of all sources
 [info] Compiling 84 Scala sources and 2 Java sources to /XXX/target/scala-2.11/classes...
 [debug] Getting compiler-interface from component compiler for Scala 2.11.2
 [debug] Getting compiler-interface from component compiler for Scala 2.11.2
 [debug] Running cached compiler 722413fe, interfacing (CompilerInterface) with Scala compiler version 2.11.2
 [debug] Calling Scala compiler with arguments  (CompilerInterface):
 [debug]    -deprecation
 [debug]    -unchecked
 [debug]    -encoding
 [debug]    utf8
 [debug]    -bootclasspath
 [debug]    /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.11.2.jar
 [debug]    -classpath
 [debug]    /XXX/target/scala-2.11/classes:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/twirl-api_2.11/jars/twirl-api_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/jars/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-xml_2.11/bundles/scala-xml_2.11-1.0.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play_2.11/jars/play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/build-link/jars/build-link-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-exceptions/jars/play-exceptions-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.javassist/javassist/bundles/javassist-3.18.2-GA.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-stm/scala-stm_2.11/jars/scala-stm_2.11-0.7.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe/config/bundles/config-1.2.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/bundles/jackson-annotations-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-core/bundles/jackson-core-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind/bundles/jackson-databind-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty/bundles/netty-3.9.2.Final.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.netty/netty-http-pipelining/jars/netty-http-pipelining-1.1.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/jars/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.6.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/jcl-over-slf4j/jars/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.6.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-core/jars/logback-core-1.1.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11/jars/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.akka/akka-slf4j_2.11/jars/akka-slf4j_2.11-2.3.4.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/commons-codec/commons-codec/jars/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/xerces/xercesImpl/jars/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/xml-apis/xml-apis/jars/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/javax.transaction/jta/jars/jta-1.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-jdbc_2.11/jars/play-jdbc_2.11-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.jolbox/bonecp/bundles/bonecp-0.8.0.RELEASE.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.h2database/h2/jars/h2-1.3.175.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/tyrex/tyrex/jars/tyrex-1.0.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/anorm_2.11/jars/anorm_2.11-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-cache_2.11/jars/play-cache_2.11-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/net.sf.ehcache/ehcache-core/jars/ehcache-core-2.6.8.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/filters-helpers_2.11/jars/filters-helpers_2.11-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-ws_2.11/jars/play-ws_2.11-2.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.google.guava/guava/bundles/guava-16.0.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.ning/async-http-client/jars/async-http-client-1.8.8.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/oauth.signpost/signpost-core/jars/signpost-core-1.2.1.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/oauth.signpost/signpost-commonshttp4/jars/signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore/jars/httpcore-4.0.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/jars/httpclient-4.0.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/commons-logging/commons-logging/jars/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-native_2.11/jars/json4s-native_2.11-3.2.10.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-core_2.11/jars/json4s-core_2.11-3.2.10.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-ast_2.11/jars/json4s-ast_2.11-3.2.10.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.thoughtworks.paranamer/paranamer/jars/paranamer-2.6.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scalap/jars/scalap-2.11.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-compiler/jars/scala-compiler-2.11.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.json4s/json4s-jackson_2.11/jars/json4s-jackson_2.11-3.2.10.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play.plugins/play-plugins-mailer_2.11/jars/play-plugins-mailer_2.11-2.3.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.apache.commons/commons-email/jars/commons-email-1.3.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/javax.mail/mail/jars/mail-1.4.5.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/javax.activation/activation/jars/activation-1.1.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play.plugins/play-plugins-util_2.11/jars/play-plugins-util_2.11-2.3.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.github.mumoshu/play2-memcached_2.11/jars/play2-memcached_2.11-0.6.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/net.spy/spymemcached/jars/spymemcached-2.9.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.github.nscala-time/nscala-time_2.11/jars/nscala-time_2.11-1.2.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.github.olim7t/sbt-scalariform/jars/sbt-scalariform-1.0.3.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scalariform/scalariform_2.8.1/jars/scalariform_2.8.1-0.0.9.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.propensive/rapture-core_2.11/jars/rapture-core_2.11-1.0.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.propensive/rapture-json-play_2.11/jars/rapture-json-play_2.11-1.0.8.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.11.4.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.propensive/rapture-json_2.11/jars/rapture-json_2.11-1.0.8.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.propensive/rapture-data_2.11/jars/rapture-data_2.11-1.0.8.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang.modules/scala-parser-combinators_2.11/bundles/scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.2.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-json_2.11/jars/play-json_2.11-2.4.0-M1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-iteratees_2.11/jars/play-iteratees_2.11-2.4.0-M1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-functional_2.11/jars/play-functional_2.11-2.4.0-M1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/com.typesafe.play/play-datacommons_2.11/jars/play-datacommons_2.11-2.4.0-M1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc-play-plugin_2.11/jars/scalikejdbc-play-plugin_2.11-2.3.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp/jars/commons-dbcp-1.4.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/commons-pool/commons-pool/jars/commons-pool-1.5.4.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/jars/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.skinny-framework/skinny-orm_2.11/jars/skinny-orm_2.11-1.3.6.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.skinny-framework/skinny-common_2.11/jars/skinny-common_2.11-1.3.6.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/joda-time/joda-time/jars/joda-time-2.6.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.joda/joda-convert/jars/joda-convert-1.7.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc_2.11/jars/scalikejdbc_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc-core_2.11/jars/scalikejdbc-core_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc-interpolation_2.11/jars/scalikejdbc-interpolation_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc-interpolation-macro_2.11/jars/scalikejdbc-interpolation-macro_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc-syntax-support-macro_2.11/jars/scalikejdbc-syntax-support-macro_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc-config_2.11/jars/scalikejdbc-config_2.11-2.2.0.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/org.flywaydb/flyway-core/jars/flyway-core-3.1.jar:/XXX/.ivy2/cache/mysql/mysql-connector-java/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.31.jar
 java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1694)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:111)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:172)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:188)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2559)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1340)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1763)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:111)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1359)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1763)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:111)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$3.apply(Trees.scala:1372)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$3.apply(Trees.scala:1372)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1371)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1763)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:111)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer$$anonfun$transformTrees$1.apply(Trees.scala:2559)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.loop$1(List.scala:172)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.mapConserve(List.scala:188)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTrees(Trees.scala:2559)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1340)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1763)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:111)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$2.apply(Trees.scala:1356)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$2.apply(Trees.scala:1354)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1353)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1763)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStat(RefChecks.scala:1250)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(RefChecks.scala:1165)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(RefChecks.scala:1165)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:327)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:1165)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:111)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1397)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1763)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:111)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transformTemplate(Trees.scala:2563)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$4.apply(Trees.scala:1401)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$4.apply(Trees.scala:1400)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1399)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1763)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStat(RefChecks.scala:1250)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(RefChecks.scala:1165)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer$$anonfun$transformStats$1.apply(RefChecks.scala:1165)
        at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:327)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:1165)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transformStats(RefChecks.scala:111)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$7.apply(Trees.scala:1419)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$$anonfun$itransform$7.apply(Trees.scala:1419)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.atOwner(Trees.scala:2600)
        at scala.reflect.internal.Trees$class.itransform(Trees.scala:1418)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.internal.SymbolTable.itransform(SymbolTable.scala:16)
        at scala.reflect.api.Trees$Transformer.transform(Trees.scala:2555)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:1763)
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:111)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ast.Trees$Transformer.transformUnit(Trees.scala:147)
        at scala.tools.nsc.transform.Transform$Phase.apply(Transform.scala:30)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.applyPhase(Global.scala:410)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:377)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Global.scala:377)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:743)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1177)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$GlobalPhase.run(Global.scala:377)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnitsInternal(Global.scala:1557)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileUnits(Global.scala:1542)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compileSources(Global.scala:1537)
        at scala.tools.nsc.Global$Run.compile(Global.scala:1644)
        at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:123)
        at xsbt.CachedCompiler0.run(CompilerInterface.scala:99)
        at xsbt.CompilerInterface.run(CompilerInterface.scala:27)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.call(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:102)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:48)
        at sbt.compiler.AnalyzingCompiler.compile(AnalyzingCompiler.scala:41)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply$mcV$sp(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$compileScala$1$1.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:99)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.sbt$compiler$AggressiveCompile$$timed(AggressiveCompile.scala:166)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.compileScala$1(AggressiveCompile.scala:98)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:143)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile$$anonfun$3.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:87)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:39)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$$anonfun$doCompile$1.apply(Compile.scala:37)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCommon.cycle(Incremental.scala:99)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:38)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$$anonfun$1.apply(Incremental.scala:37)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.manageClassfiles(Incremental.scala:65)
        at sbt.inc.Incremental$.compile(Incremental.scala:37)
        at sbt.inc.IncrementalCompile$.apply(Compile.scala:27)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile2(AggressiveCompile.scala:157)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.compile1(AggressiveCompile.scala:71)
        at sbt.compiler.AggressiveCompile.apply(AggressiveCompile.scala:46)
        at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:75)
        at sbt.Compiler$.apply(Compiler.scala:66)
        at sbt.Defaults$.sbt$Defaults$$compileTaskImpl(Defaults.scala:770)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:762)
        at sbt.Defaults$$anonfun$compileTask$1.apply(Defaults.scala:762)
        at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
        at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:42)
        at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:64)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:18)
        at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:244)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:237)
        at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:160)
        at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:30)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
 [error] (compile:compile) java.lang.NullPointerException
        at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.RefChecks$RefCheckTransformer.transform(RefChecks.scala:111)
```

**build.sbt**

```
name := ""XXXXX"""

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  filters,
  ws,
  "com.typesafe.play.plugins" %%  "play-plugins-mailer"       % "2.3.0",
  "com.github.mumoshu"        %%  "play2-memcached"           % "0.6.0",  
  "com.github.nscala-time"    %%  "nscala-time"               % "1.2.0",
  "com.propensive"            %%  "rapture-core"              % "1.0.0",
  "com.propensive"            %%  "rapture-json-play"         % "1.0.8",
  "org.scalikejdbc"           %%  "scalikejdbc-play-plugin"   % "2.3.1",
  "org.skinny-framework"      %%  "skinny-orm"                % "1.3.6",
  "ch.qos.logback"            %   "logback-classic"           % "1.1.2"
)

scalikejdbcSettings
```

**plugins.sbt**

```
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// The Play plugin
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.2")

// web plugins

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-coffeescript" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-less" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-jshint" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-rjs" % "1.0.1")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-digest" % "1.0.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-mocha" % "1.0.0")

libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.31"

addSbtPlugin("org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc-mapper-generator" % "2.1.1")
```

**build.properties**

```
#Activator-generated Properties
#Tue Aug 26 10:07:37 JST 2014
template.uuid=b614e6e8-f302-41a5-b57e-5478c4149f68
sbt.version=0.13.6
```

全く原因分からないんですが、これで通る、通らないが変わるようです。

コンパイルが通る

```
◯ case class Report[A](key: Int, data: A)
```

コンパイルが通らない

```
× case class Report[A](key: String, data: A)
```

Comment: Scala コンパイラのバグのように見えますが、情報が少なすぎるため断定はできません。可能ならば、同様の症状が発生するソースコード一式を公開すると、より良い回答が得られる確率が高まるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 特定の条件で必ず発生するのか、sbtならcleanすればなおるのか、
(コンパイラのバグと断定する前に) コンパイラプラグインやマクロを使っているか？(そうだとすると、コンパイラプラグインやマクロ側のバグの可能性もある)などの情報もないと判断できないですね

Comment: このエラーとは関係ない可能性のほうが高いけど、path見ると、playの2.4.0-M1と2.3.2が混ざってるのはなぜでしょう？(バイナリ互換が無いはずなので混ぜてはだめ)

Comment: あと  `org.scalariform/scalariform_2.8.1/jars/scalariform_2.8.1-0.0.9` というかなり古い、バイナリ互換ないものも含まれてる？ `com.github.olim7t/sbt-scalariform/jars/sbt-scalariform-1.0.3.jar` も？

Comment: @KoRoN さん、@kenji-yoshida さん

ありがとうございます！マクロは自分では使っていませんが、ライブラリ内部（skinnyやrapture等）では使っているようです。
また、playのバージョンが混ざっているのは、rapture-json-playの1.0.8がplay2.4-M1に依存しているようです。
jsonBackEndsを別のものに置き換えないといけないですね。。

プロダクトなのでソースコードは公開出来ませんが、build.sbtとplugins.sbt、build.propertiesのみ公開します。何かわかれば幸いです。

Answer (score 3):

完全に原因分かりました。

コンパイルが通る

```
case class Report[A](key: Int, data: A)
```

通らない

```
case class Report[A](key: String, data: A)
```

だったのですが、別の場所でこういったimplicit defを定義しておりました。

```
  implicit def reportExtractor[A](implicit extractor: Extractor[A, Json]): Extractor[Api.Report[A], Json] = BasicExtractor { x =>
    val js = x.asInstanceOf[Json]
    Api.Report(js.id.as[Int], js.data.as[A])
  }
```

そして、この「Extractor[A, Json]」がrapture内のマクロで生成されるため、エラーがimplicit defではなく、case class実装側で出ていました。
sbtのバグではなかったです。

（ただ、このマクロ実装側でエラーが出て、しかもなんだかよく分からないログしか出ないという仕様を何とかしてほしいなぁ、と思いました）

コメント頂いた方、ありがとうございました。

Comment: 一応自分の予想が少しは当たった(?)ようでよかったです。

"このマクロ実装側でエラーが出て、しかもなんだかよく分からないログしか出ないという仕様"

という件ですが、マクロのライブラリによるけれど、ある程度はそういうデメリットを覚悟の上でないと、初心者はあまり手軽にマクロを使うべきではないと思います。エラーメッセージに限らず、まだマクロは実験的機能であり、使いこなせば強力だけれど、微妙な部分も多いので